# Assign a value to a control in the datagridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to assign a value to a textbox depending on the selected value of the dropdownlist. But I try this getting  the error

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Here is my code:

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in cgvRequest.Rows)
{
    //Programmatically access the CheckBox from the TemplateField

    //CheckBoxField chk = (CheckBoxField)gvr.FindControl("chkMark");
    Label lbl = (Label)gvr.FindControl("lblRequestAmount");

    TextBox _txtAmount = (TextBox)cgvRequest.FindControl("txtAmount");

    lbl.Text = Convert.ToString(
                   requestinfo.ElementAt(gvr.RowIndex).AmountRequested);

    DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
    ddl = (DropDownList)cgvRequest.FindControl("ddlApprovalType");

    ddl.SelectedValue = "A";
    _txtAmount.Text = lbl.Text;
}
```

Comment: In which line do you get the error?

Comment: i get the error on the last two lines

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you are getting

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

is that  the control (dropdownlist and/or textbox) you are trying to set a property to is `null`. Which means it cannot be found by `FindControl()` method.

I am just assuming this because I cannot debug your code, but I bet it is because you are calling `FindControl` on the data grid and not on the row.

Try changing your code to:

```
TextBox _txtAmount = (TextBox)gvr.FindControl("txtAmount");
```

and

```
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
ddl = (DropDownList)gvr.FindControl("ddlApprovalType");
```

Answer (score 0):

IF your textbox "txtAmount" and DropDownList "ddlApprovalType" are in gridview row, then why are you trying to get this from gridview itself.
You should use the same code, which you are using for Label "lblRequestAmount".             `TextBox _txtAmount = (TextBox)gvr.FindControl("txtAmount");`
Please let me know if it doesnt solve your problem. Please post few more details like on which line you are getting this error. and post you gridview designer code too.

Comment: The error is occured when I was try to assign a value for dropdownlist and textbox. That is the last two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Check Label.text getting values or it's null.After that assign the values to the Textbox.

you got an Error from last two lines Right..?

can u post me your full code of that code behind, gridview designer Code as well as Event..?

Actually what you are trying Explain me clearly..?

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.   Since it seems you have not yet discovered how to accept answers.